# How to create possible set and sum dictionary value of same key on RDD pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a sample of data below and I wrote my code to convert a dictionary to sum dictionary value that has the same key.

```
import itertools
d = [frozenset({'112', 'a', 'e'}), frozenset({'112', 'a', 'e', 'd'})]
rdd = sc.parallelize(d)

def f_itemset(data):    
   d = {}
   for i in range(1, len(data)+1):
        for x in itertools.combinations(data, i+1):                 
            if x not in d:
                d[x] += 1
            else:
                d[x] = 1

    return d
Ck = rdd.map(lambda s: sorted([l for l in s])).map(lambda x: [f_itemset(x))
print(Ck.collect())
```

The output is shown below.

```
[{('112', 'a'): 1, ('112', 'e'): 1, ('a', 'e'): 1, ('112', 'a', 'e'): 1}, {('112', 'a'): 1, ('112', 'd'): 1, ('112', 'e'): 1, ('a', 'd'): 1, ('a', 'e'): 1, ('d', 'e'): 1, ('112', 'a', 'd'): 1, ('112', 'a', 'e'): 1, ('112', 'd', 'e'): 1, ('a', 'd', 'e'): 1, ('112', 'a', 'd', 'e'): 1}]
```

But, I want the output is:

```
[{('112', 'a'): 2, ('112', 'e'): 2, ('a', 'e'): 2, ('112', 'a', 'e'): 2,  ('112', 'd'): 1, ('a', 'd'): 1, ('d', 'e'): 1, ('112', 'a', 'd'): 1, ('112', 'd', 'e'): 1, ('a', 'd', 'e'): 1, ('112', 'a', 'd', 'e'): 1}]
```

Please, anyone, advise me.

Answer (score 0):

I omitted some of your initial statements and included an additional reduceByKey method to achieve the counting. Unfortunately, it is by default only possible to process lists with reduceByKey. If you really want to stick to dictionaries you have to create an own method for the reduction. Otherwise this code can help you.

```py
import itertools
d = [frozenset({'112', 'a', 'e'}), frozenset({'112', 'a', 'e', 'd'})]
rdd = sc.parallelize(d)

def f_itemset(data):    
   l = list()
   for i in range(1, len(data)+1):
       for x in itertools.combinations(data, i+1):                 
           l.append(x)
return l
Ck = rdd.map(lambda s: sorted([l for l in s])).flatMap(lambda x: f_itemset(x)).map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)

print(Ck.collect())
```

Result:

```py
[(('112', 'e'), 2), (('a', 'd', 'e'), 1), (('112', 'd'), 1), (('112', 'a'), 2), (('a', 'e'), 2), (('112', 'a', 'd', 'e'), 1), (('a', 'd'), 1), (('d', 'e'), 1), (('112', 'a', 'e'), 2), (('112', 'a', 'd'), 1), (('112', 'd', 'e'), 1)]
```